# No module named 'vmtkactivetubes'

Tags: python, spyder, vtk

In my Python code, I have :

from vmtk import vmtkscripts

The program has no issue finding "vmtkscripts.py". 
However, in vmtkscripts.py I have "

`__all__ = ['vmtkactivetubes']`

```
for item in __all__:
    exec('from '+item+' import *')
```

where "vmtkactivetubes.py" is in the same folder as "vmtkscripts.py".

After running I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vmtkactivetubes'"
However, this "from vmtk import vmtkactivetubes" doesn't give me any error.

I would really appreciate if you could help me, why I get such a error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of scope,

try using:

```
exec('from '+item+' import *', globals())
```

This from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed
>   in the current scope. If only globals is provided, it must be a
>   dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local
>   variables. If globals and locals are given, they are used for the
>   global and local variables, respectively. If provided, locals can be
>   any mapping object. Remember that at module level, globals and locals
>   are the same dictionary. If exec gets two separate objects as globals
>   and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a
>   class definition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I still receive same error! :(